The max-height of accordion element causes delay when folding with a cubic bezier animation
I created an accordion in React, but when I expand an item of it it takes a while before it collapses.
Now, I found out why that takes a while. It's because the height of the hidden part (in this case, the definition), has a max-height: 500px, so it takes a while before that 500px has collapsed. When I try this with height: auto, it doesn't work.
Is there any way to solve this problem? What I want is the .Definition div to be as high as its content, so the collapse goes smooth.
This is (a small part) of the CSS for the accordion, it shows the definition (hidden), and it pops up when clicking a button that is defined somewhere else.
.Definition {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0.55, 0.265, 0.15);

        &.show {
          max-height: 200px;
        }
      }



You can not transition to or from height: auto - that's why the explicit max-height is used as a "workaround" here. If you don't like the delay effect this causes for items that are less high than this value - then you need to use JavaScript to measure the actual content height, and then explicitly set that as the height to transition to.

if support isn't an issue, check this answer for a simple way to transition to height auto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022592/8620333
